# Deserialize protected constructor with Jackson

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

Hi I'm trying to use jackson to serialize and deserialize a class(SimpleExpression) with protected constructor. When I use gson I don't have any problem for that, but it seems that jackson can't handle protected constructors. I tried using mixin-annotations but didn't worked. Serialization works without any problem. Jackson throws:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type
```

Any help?
My code:

```
private static SimpleExpression create(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY);
    SimpleExpression sp = null;
    sp = mapper.readValue(json, SimpleExpression.class);
    return sp;
}
```

SimpleExpression class, i'm omiting the getter and setters.

```
public class SimpleExpression implements Criterion
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final String propertyName;

private final Object value;

private boolean ignoreCase;

private final String op;

private final String type;

protected SimpleExpression(String propertyName, Object value, String op)
{
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
    this.value = value;
    this.op = op;
    this.type = value.getClass().getName();
}

protected SimpleExpression(String propertyName, Object value, String op, boolean ignoreCase)
{
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
    this.value = value;
    this.ignoreCase = ignoreCase;
    this.op = op;
    this.type = value.getClass().getName();
}
}
```

Comment: You should include class def of `SimpleExpression`, since that's what is missing something.

Comment: I forgot about that, just did.

Answer (score 3):

Protected part should not be problematic (they are found ok) but perhaps constructor takes arguments. To indicate non-default constructor to use, you use `@JsonCreator`; but beyond that it depends on what kind of constructor (or static factory method) to use.

But to know details, class definition is needed. Another possibility is that you are trying to deal with non-static inner class.

Comment: Yes it takes arguments, but if I dont have access to class constructor, from a library, I can't annotate it ,right? So to rebuild an object i need to annotate the constructor, without that Jackson will try to use a no-arg constructor?

Comment: Correct, without annotations Jackson can't figure out other ctors (since ctor parameter names are not stored in bytecode). But you can still use mix-in annotations, see [http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations], even for constructors (not just methods or fields).

Comment: Wrt mix-in annotation: you then just define dummy class with matching constructor (same argument types in same order); mark that with `@JsonCreator`, and each parameter with `@JsonProperty` that specifies which JSON name it matches. That should work, once you register mix-in annotation for `ObjectMapper`

Comment: The non-static inner class thing was the solution to my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just if any1 comes to the thread.
I was having the same issue.
I just add a constructor

```
protected SimpleExpression(){}
```

and it worked fine

Comment: This won't compile as the final attributes are not initialized. It would work if you explicitly set each attribute to null or a default value.